# How to programmatically open docx then convert to pdf in memory and then get byte content of pdf in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, arrays, docx

I need to open docx that's stored in sharepoint then convert it to pdf in memory and then write to http response so pdf would be downloaded at client machine.

The issue is I don't know how to convert pdf to byte array in memory. There is a condition: I can use only free libs and third-side API. Microsoft.Interop offers to save docx as pdf to disk, for example:

```
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
doc.Activate();

object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

// Save document into PDF Format
doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

but I need to get bytes and write them to response directly without saving data on disk.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to apply more comprehensive one-stop solution without reference to SharePoint. Let's say in some ASP.NET site.

Comment: Not viable to write the PDF to a temp file, read the bytes, then delete the file? EDIT: Also, the `wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf")` scares me. Consider the file name "chris.doctornotes.doc" or "josh.dockery.resume.doc"

Comment: Thanks for response. No, using a temp file isn't acceptable. EDIT: Yeah, that code needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise the Word Automation Services Service in SharePoint 2010.  There is a nice example at http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/using-sharepoint-2010-word-automation-services-to-convert-document-synchronously/ of how to do this in a synchronous manner.

Comment: I'd like to apply more comprehensive one-stop solution without reference to SharePoint. Let's say in some ASP.NET site.